# Connection using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Just started working with PDO.Please explain me the error in my connectivity.It always shows "You are connected".

```
    <?php

       define('user','root');
       define('pass','');
       define('db','login_db');

       try
          {
       $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host = localhost; dbname = db",user,pass);
       echo "You are connected";
          }
       catch(PDOException $e)
          {
       echo $e -> getMessage(); 
          }
    ?>
```

Also provide with some tutorial or ebook for PDO you aware with. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't really look like an error.

Comment: I don't think you understand your code. As you can see it, in your try you are calling the PDO class and make the connection. It doesn't seem like an error because you are have declared it to echo or print "You are connected";

Comment: Other than your un-interpolated `db` constant and spaces around the `=` signs (not sure if this is [actually a problem](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php)), I don't see anything wrong here

Comment: you have successfully connected. You can continue your rest of coding. $dbh holds your connection

Comment: Thanks to all for reply. But when I am missspelling 'localhost' or 'dbname' then also it says You are connected.

Comment: @Phil you hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by 2 syntax errors in your Data Source Name (DSN) (the first argument in the PDO connection string).

### The errors

1. You cannot pass your db constant into the connection string as `"...dbname = db"`.  Since `db` is wrapped in double quotes and will be interpretted as a string instead of a constant.
2. You cannot have spaces in your DSN. It should be:

   ```
   "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=login_db" //no spaces.
   ```

I've tested this and it exhibits some strange behaviour:

- Specifically, it seems that the space between `host` and the first `=` sign causes the problem. If there is a space, it will echo `"You are connected"` even if "localhost" is misspelled.
- Similarly, if there is a space between `dbname` and its `=` sign, it will appear to connect even if the specified database name is incorrect.

My guess is that this is some quirk of how the PDO class parses the DSN.

### The solution

Remove all the spaces from the DSN.

You also need to pass in your database name in a different way.  There are different ways to fix this.  I would recommend, for the sake of not getting any more weird-to-debug-errors, that you use variables instead of constant definitions:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db   = 'login_db';

try{
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass);
    echo "You are connected";
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e -> getMessage(); 
}
```

---

As for good tutorials, you can look at these:

[Net.tuts+ : PHP Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/)

[Net.tuts+ : Why use PDOs](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

And of course the don't forget the php.net docs.

[php.net : PDOs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Thanks a ton Jonathan.Not providing space in between worked.

Answer (score 0):

Constant identifiers should be uppercase:

```
 define('USER','root');
```

If you want to use constants you can do it this way:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host = ". HOST .";dbname=" . DB ,USER,PASS);
```

Comment: Constants identifiers are only uppercase by convention. The case is not the problem

Comment: Constant indentifiers may be defined in lower case as well.Just dont provide space in DSN as Jonathan explained above and your code work as well.Thanks for your reply.